# List itemRenderer drag over detect

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

[image]

As the pic shows, suppose List1 of item1 drag to List2 of item iv, I want the item iv to detect the drag over state and hightlight itself, so how to implement it?

Comment: An exact answer to your question lies at http://www.davidortinau.com/blog/catch_mouseover_event_when_dragging_another_object/

Answer (score 1):

Attach a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` listener to each of the list elements, that checks if you're dragging anything, and if so, `event.target` gets highlighted.

Comment: It doesn't fit for the situation. I only want the items of List2 get highlighted when List1 item drag over it. If attach MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, the item of List2 will highlighted even if it's not triggered by the drag behavior.

Comment: @Vesper, Here is my solution. In the List2, I listen for the DRAG_OVER and DRAG_DROP event, in both the event handler, calculate the drop index, use layout.target.getElementAt() to get the List item, and then invoke item.highlight(). But I'm stuck with another issue, what if change the drop item when still dragging(e.g. from item iv to item iii), how to undo the former item highlight?

Comment: @Allan, could you have a look about the latest comment?

Comment: Listen to MOUSE_OUT? It'll anyway force your list item to unhioghlight.

Comment: @Vesper, I figure out it, you could have a look at it:).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and code:
for **List2**:

```
<s:List
itemRenderer="components.MyRenderer"
dragEnter="myDragEnterHandler(event)"
dragOver="myDragOverHandler(event)"
dragExit="myDragExitHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function myDragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
            //we shoudld make List2 be drop target
            DragManager.acceptDragDrop(e.currentTarget as IUIComponent);              
        }

        private function myDragOverHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
            var dropIndex:int = calDropIndex(event);
            var element:MyRenderer= calDropItem(dropIndex);
            //undo highlight if there is last over item
            if(lastOverItem) {
               lastOverItem.undoHighlight();            
            }
            //remember the last highlight one and highlight it
            lastOverItem = element;     
            element.highlight(); 
        }

        private function myDragExitHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
             var dropIndex:int = calDropIndex(event);
             var element:MyRenderer= calDropItem(dropIndex);
             element.undoHighlight(); 
        }

        private function calDropIndex(event:DragEvent):int {
             var dropLocation:DropLocation = 
                 event.currentTarget.layout.calculateDropLocation(event);
             var dropIndex:int = dropLocation.dropIndex;
             return dropIndex;
       }

       private function calDropItem(dropIndex:int):MyRenderer{
           var element:IVisualElement;
           if (layout.useVirtualLayout) {
            element = layout.target.getVirtualElementAt(dropIndex);
           } else {
            element = layout.target.getElementAt(dropIndex);
           }
           return element as MyRenderer;
      }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</S:List>
```